# Problem with uploading files using FTP

Tags: c#, file-upload

I am working on windows application with c#.net .
I am using FTPwebrequest class for upload file on ftp.it works fine when there is no proxy between application and internet. but it doesn't work in proxy.

`FtpWebRequest reqFTP;`
if i use `reqFTP.Proxy=new webproxy("proxyservername",21);`
then it will display error message "FTP command doen't support in HTTP proxy".

my code is like this

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://uri");

reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");

reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;

reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
int buffLength = 2048;

byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
int contentLen;

FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

while (contentLen != 0)
{
    strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
    prbUpload.Value += contentLen;
}

strm.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [FtpWebRequest.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) property documentation:

> If the specified proxy is an HTTP
>   proxy, only the `DownloadFile`,
>   `ListDirectory`, and
>   `ListDirectoryDetails` commands are
>   supported.

So you cannot use `FtpWebRequest` to upload a file using FTP through an HTTP proxy. Other solutions might be available, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161200/ftp-file-upload-with-http-proxy) that discusses the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTTP proxy. May be you use this proxy to browse internet. You cannot use http proxy for ftp. To use that proxy for ftp, you need to configure the proxy server for ftp.

Bottom line is, ftp proxy is required for ftp, http proxy is required for browsing etc..

So, you are sending ftp commands through proxy, but that proxy supports only http. So, I think the error message is now more meaningful to you

"**FTP command** doen't support in **HTTP proxy**"

Comment: how i can configure  the proxy server for ftp Programatically.

Comment: you cannot. the proxy server is a computer running a software. that software is required to be configured. You cannot configure it programmatically from your app, it will be like trying to configure stackoverflow.com webserver using your app.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's uploadFile, DownloadFile, ListDirectory, or ListDirectoryDetails, The following code resolves all the problems.

```
reqFTP.Proxy = new WebProxy();
```

It will initializes Proxy to empty instance of the WebProxy Class which will internally skip the proxy.