# How to upload using FTP in Powershell, behind a proxy?

Tags: powershell, proxy, ftp

I am attempting to use FTP in Powershell to upload a file. I am using `FtpWebRequest` later followed by `GetRequestStream`, but this method is returning an error:

> "The requested FTP command is not supported when using HTTP proxy."

I am indeed behind a proxy and required to be.

How can I upload via Powershell when behind a proxy?

This would be solely run from a `.ps1` Powershell script.

I have also tried:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($server)

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, "C:\Test\1234567.txt")
```

Where `$server` and that file are valid. But that code returns this error:

```
"An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At C:\Test\script.ps1:101 char:26
+     $webclient.UploadFile <<<< ($uri, "C:\Test\1234567.txt")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I also tried double backslashes in the file paths, didn't help.

The proxy I am under only touches HTTP, and not FTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your proxy supports FTP, or is it HTTP only? See this thread:

[FTP File Upload with HTTP Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161200/ftp-file-upload-with-http-proxy)

For WebClient I've used this in the past although it was for HTTP use, but you could give it a try:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent","Mozilla/4.0+")        
$wc.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$wc.UploadFile($uri, "C:\Test\1234567.txt")
```

Note that - "The UploadFile method sends a local file to a resource. This method uses the STOR command to upload an FTP resource. For an HTTP resource, the POST method is used."

Comment: I've checked, and the proxy I am under only touches HTTP and not FTP. I'm trying that code but getting `Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exception:

> Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Tracing showed, that when I used a ftp-uri and added a proxy to the webclient, no connections were initiated. (neither to server nor to proxy)

I am behind a ftp-proxy with authentication and the only way, it worked for me, was:

```
$LocalFile = "C:\Temp\test.csv"
$FtpFile = "ftp://$ProxyUser:$ProxyPassword@$ProxyServer:21/ftp_test.csv"

$uri = New-Object System.Uri($FtpFile)
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$FtpUser@$FtpServer","$FtpPassword")
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $LocalFile)
```