# C# - FTP with Proxy append string to file

Tags: c#, text, proxy, ftp, append

I am trying to append a String to a text file on my ftp server.
As i read in microsoft's developer network this is not supported for HTTP proxies.

> If the specified proxy is an HTTP proxy, only the DownloadFile,
>   ListDirectory, and >ListDirectoryDetails commands are supported.

now because my company uses a ftp proxy, i tried to go with something i read in this thread:

[FTP File Upload with HTTP Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161200/ftp-file-upload-with-http-proxy)

> most FTP proxies do their thing on the connection, so if you had NO
>   proxy, you do this:
>
> **server: myftpserver.com user: me password: pwd**
>
> using an FTP proxy, you do:
>
> **server: ftpproxy.mydomain.com user: me@myftpserver.com password: pwd**

The problem with this is though .. i didn't know where i can choose the path on my server .. since i entered it as a "username"

i tried a lot now but didn't get it to work ..
my question is: has anyone ever successfully appended a string to a text file using FTP **with** a FTP Proxy?
can anyone suggest me a good third party library to deal with this? i've come across Xceed FTP and Rebex .. but they are both commercial ..

cheers!
phil

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an HTTP proxy for FTP, then it is either:

1) [FTP over HTTP](https://community.mcafee.com/docs/DOC-4921#What_Is_it) - this is actually an HTTP proxy which can deal with ftp:// URLs (see Steffen Ullrich's reply). In this case, you are essentially using HTTP protocol (not FTP) at the client (the proxy acts as a translation layer). Because of this, the functionality is somewhat limited. Only basic FTP operations are supported and it seems to be somewhat proxy-specific.

2) [HTTP CONNECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_Tunneling) - most HTTP proxies support the "CONNECT" method. This can be used to establish a tunnel through the proxy to a specified server/port. It is mostly used to tunnel HTTPS traffic and some proxies only allow connections to specific ports (such as 443 used by HTTPS). However, if the proxy allows tunnelling to any port, HTTP CONNECT can be (mis)used to tunnel FTP protocol (as long as passive mode is used for all transfers). In that case, all FTP operations are possible, including appending to a file or resuming transfer.

Most commercial FTP components support HTTP CONNECT proxies (Rebex [does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/919660/277341)). For FTP over HTTP, I would rather suggest looking for a good HTTP component instead.

Comment: well, how can i find out which one my company got?
one thing i know is that we have two different ports on the proxy, one for ftp and one for http .. does this help?

Comment: Easiest would be asking your network admin. If it's not viable you can try to write code which connects using various proxy types and test which one works. Sample code can be found here: http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/features/proxy.aspx (no need to purchase the full package, trial version will be enough for testing)

Comment: If you have a separate port for FTP on the proxy, then it's quite possible it's neither *FTP over HTTP* nor *HTTP CONNECT*, but a real FTP proxy (see Steffen Ullrich's reply). In that case, appeding to a file or resuming transfer should be possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have a real FTP proxy (e.g. which speaks the FTP protocol) or you have a HTTP proxy which can deal with ftp:// URLs too. In the latter case there is no probably no way to append data to an existing file.

If you have instead a real FTP proxy you should be able to just use your usual FTP library and only adapt the login process. Mostly something like logging in as "user@host" at the FTP proxy is used to make it forward the FTP connection to host, but the details depend on the proxy. And once you have your proxied FTP connection you can issue APPE command to add data to an existing file, e.g. like with a un-proxied FTP connection.